# Call a shell script method with parameter using nohup

Tags: shell, nohup

**/bin/scripts/first.ksh**

```
#!/bin/bash
start(){
   first="$1";
   echo "arg is $first"
}
```

**/bin/scripts/second.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup sh /bin/scripts/first.ksh start arg1 > nohup_log 2>&1 &
```

The argument is not picked up.
What is the correct way to pass argument in the second script?

Comment: You are running the script `first.ksh` using sh (not bash .... there is no bash involved in your code) with two parameters. The script you have posted only defines a function, but does not pick up any of its parameters, and never calls the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass parameters, you have to use them somehow. One possibility is technically do write your script as

```
start(){
 first="$1";
 echo "arg is $first"
}

"$@"
```

The last line would - in your case - expand to `start arg1` and therefore call your function. **However it is risky to do this**: Since the first parameter to your script (i.e. *start*) is treated as a command to be executed, the user of the script could inject any code via the parameter. This is a serious security hole.

I would at least verify the first parameter somehow, or redesign your script completely. For instance, it is unclear why you define a function, if the script isn't doing anything else than calling this function.